# Where to buy premium white chalk in the U.S., like they have at RIMS?

Tags: teaching

While not a research-level math question, I'm sure this is a question of interest to many research-level mathematicians, whose expertise I seek.

At RIMS (in Kyoto) in 2005, they had the best white chalk I've seen anywhere. It's slightly larger than standard American chalk, harder, heavier, and most importantly covered with some enamel-like coating that one must rub through (on the end) to be able to write with. One's hands don't rub through the coating, and thus don't get chalky.

Are there any U.S. manufacturers of such?

EDIT: even though someone has given a link whereby to order this stuff from Japan, I would still be delighted to hear about American products that beat Binney & Smith.

Comment: I went to the second annual "Current Developments in Mathematics" conference some years back, at a conference center in Boston. They slid the wall with the projector screen aside, to expose the blackboard. It still had the notes on it from the _previous year's_ conference.

Comment: I went to a conf center in Boston a few years ago, and the main secretary (who had been there 2 years) was excited/intrigued that I was the first person to ask about using overhead transparencies. I think technology used differs by subject area. I've seen some groups where almost no one used computer slides, and others where almost everyone did. Someone told me there were a couple of slate chalkboards somewhere in Berkeley still (a decade ago) that were really nice. I've also been told that printing (opposed to cursive) slows you down, but only if the chalk is high quality. A strange theory.

Comment: Another piece of miracle Japanese technology is the eraser cleaners they have now (at least in Tokyo Inst. of Technology).  It really helps reduce the chalk dust in the room tremendously.

Comment: Could the question at least be aimed at an international audience?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

<strike>You can buy it online [rakuten link deleted]</strike>

**Edit (2020-7-10):** Hagoromo Bunku company has been shut down in March 2015 ([Berkeley Alumni Magazine article](https://alumni.berkeley.edu/california-magazine/fall-2019/chalk-market-where-mathematicians-go-get-good-stuff)).  There were two successors to their product, because the three custom machines they had for making chalk were sold to two parties.

1. Two machines, together with the rights to the "Hagoromo Fulltouch" name were sold to [Sejongmall](http://en.sejongmall.co.kr), a South Korean company.  They have US dollar prices and ship internationally.  Incidentally, the splash screen on their site has pictures of Brian Conrad and Andrei Okounkov pulled from a Japanese TV show about the chalk.
2. One machine was sold to Uma-jirushi, a Japanese blackboard maker with plans to expand to chalk. In April 2015 Uma-jirushi announced a new product called DC Chalk Deluxe (DCチョークDX) as "a collaboration with Hagoromo" in its catalog.  However, Uma-jirushi [announced on 2020-1-26](https://www.uma-jirushi.co.jp/info/7895) that they would discontinue sales of DC chalk on 2020-5-31.

Comment: I'm actually curious enough that I just bought two boxes of that chalk... I think... the part with the shipping options was in Japanese.

Comment: For those who don't click through, they'll charge $14 + $5/box for shipping. The actual chalk is $6/box.

Comment: ...and one box contains 72 sticks of chalk.

Comment: The boxes come with a special spacing grid separating the chalk sticks, so that they don't touch each other in the box. 

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Did you actually get that chalk? Any review comments for the general public?  (And the link in this answer being broken, is it actually the same as from the other answers: Hagaromo "Fulltouch"?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster Nope, never got them.

Comment: The very sad news, which I got from a Japanese colleague yesterday, is that Rakuten is closing end of March because of some economical issue. So, hurry up!

Comment: You link to a 100+ page catalog. Please specify the page.

Comment: For US customers, Amazon appears to still have Fulltouch.  Simply search "Hagoromo Fulltouch" and the standard white/colored products appear.  Furthermore, expedited shipping appears as an option, so I would be very surprised if they are out of stock...

Comment: +1 For keeping this post up-to-date.

Comment: I only want to buy one or two sticks of Fulltouch as a present for my lecturer. It's too expensive otherwise. Can I arrange that with anybody? Even if you only reply in a few months, I'm still interested.

Comment: I rolled back an edit which seemed to merely be self-promotion by a user of their company

Comment: @YemonChoi why did you just rollback to a DEAD link? That serves no one. I might not have high reputation here, but I'm well ranked on Stackoverflow. Someone brought this post to my attention and my edit can serves to help people who wish to buy nearly anything from Japan. Your rollback doesn't improve this answer.

Comment: @MaxHodges if you can procure said chalk then please feel free to supply a new answer with actual details. Please note that this question dates from the early days of MathOverflow and a lot of the site's norms and practices concerning "what is an appropriate question" have changed. I also don't see how being high-ranked on StackOverflow has any relevance.

Comment: @YemonChoi can't mate: it's [CLOSED]

Comment: If it helps anyone, there are proxy buying services in Japan that could have helped you buy nearly anything from Japan. Just google "proxy buying Japan" or "Japan buying service" should you come across some kind of "Japan-only" item in the future.

Comment: Obviously, we're all not buying enough of this chalk.

Comment: I swear to my chalks that I wrote the rakuten link above. For your info, a box of 72 Fulltouch chalks of Hagoromo Bungu now costs > 150 usd in rakuten and > 100 usd in amazon.co.jp. I myself just ordered a box of 72 Fulltouch chalks of Sejongmall from amazon.co.jp to give a try. This costs me around 20 usd.

Answer (score 105):

We here in New York have also long sought to secure supplies of this amazingly high quality chalk. It is called [Hagoromo "Fulltouch"](http://www.hagoromo-bungu.co.jp/chalk/fulltouch.html) chalk, and my colleague Jonas Reitz wrote to the company, since the chalk does not seem to be available anywhere in the US, and got a letter in reply *directly from the company president* (with fairly OK English) concerning prices and rates to the US. It would come to 3 dollars per stick, and we considered that.

Meanwhile, one of our postdocs with connections to Japan was able to arrange a small supply that way, and this is the message our administrative assistant sent out (provided with permission):

> > To All GC Math Ph.D. Program Faculty,
> >
> > I am happy to report that we have managed (thorough the good graces of our postdoc Yu Yasufuku) to get a limited supply of Hagoromo "Fulltouch" chalk which is made in Japan and is not available for sale in the United States.  We have been trying unsuccessfully to get this “miracle” chalk for years, but finally our prayers have been answered.  Users of this chalk report that it is the “Rolls Royce” of chalk; for you oenophiles, it may be thought of as the “Chateau Lafite Rothschild” of chalk, or, for you baseball fans, the “Babe Ruth” of chalk… well, you get the idea.
> >
> > I have heard it said that it is impossible to make a mathematical mistake when writing with this chalk, but I am somewhat dubious of this claim.
> >
> > The chalk was “smuggled” in stick by stick carried in the beaks of birds (well, practically), so the supply is very limited.  We have, however, worked out a distribution system that seems the fairest and that should allow our stash to last for about 3 semesters. Faculty members teaching at GC will get ten sticks of chalk per semester, and those not teaching but who are coordinating (or co-coordinating) a math seminar at the GC and is a member of the Math Doctoral Faculty will each get 2 sticks per semester.  This will repeat each semester until the chalk is gone.  Faculty should save this chalk for use only during their most important lectures or when working on their most important theorems.
> >
> > If you currently fall into one of the two categories listed above, please stop by to see me for your chalk and I will check you off of my list.  Hopefully, after spring 2011, another supply of these magical white sticks can be procured on the black or gray market, or perhaps Hagoromo will begin distribution in the U.S.
> >
> > At any rate, enjoy your chalk!  Use it wisely.
> >
> > Best,
> >
> > Rob
> >
> > Robert S. Landsman, Assistant Program Officer, CUNY Ph.D. Program in Mathematics

Comment: I'm so glad to know the name of the manufacturer, thanks! I am loath to mark the question "answered", though, insofar as I still hope someone will suggest a no doubt inferior alternative that's still better than Binney & Smith.

Comment: Here is an interview with the company founder about why he has now regretfully closed the company: http://asia.nikkei.com/Business/Companies/Hagoromo-president-explains-why-he-closed-down-his-beloved-chalk-business

Answer (score 59):

My company started selling Hagoromo Fulltouch Chalk through Amazon.
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007R76ND2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007R76ND2)

If you have any question, please contact me at
kyung@tenbyteninc.com
510-652-1492

Thank you.
Kyung

**Edit:** Now you can buy Hagoromo Fulltouch Chalk in color.
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=bl_sr_office-products/189-2317706-1220456?_encoding=UTF8&field-brandtextbin=Hagoromo%20Bungu&node=1064954

Comment: And I've already received my first box as a present!  Thank you!

Comment: Is it also possible to get colored chalk via Amazon?

Comment: This answer amazingly manages not to be spam despite being an advertisement.

Answer (score 13):

Following on S. Okada's post, I recently ordered 12 boxes (864 pieces) for just under $25 per box, or 3 sticks/dollar. [Rakuten](http://global.rakuten.com/en/store/bung-man/item/fc720l/) only ships within Japan, but [Tenso](http://www.tenso.com/en/)
will forward the package abroad for roughly twice the cost of the package itself. However, Tenso is having a promotion till 28 Feb 2012, first 5000 yen discounted to 1000 yen. For a few boxes, jump on this, this is your chance. I went way over so it didn't save me much.

Even though Rakuten won't ship the chalk abroad, their English web form requires a complete US address before a person gets to look at the order. This is easy: Give your US address, but in the comments field, give your Tenso address. This worked just fine for me.

My credit card company put a fraud alert on Rakuten's charge, which canceled the order. Somewhat reasonable if Rakuten doesn't ship to the US, where I am. I had to place the order again, after clearing the fraud alert. Better to warn your credit card company in advance.

My breakdown, 12 boxes was 7092 yen plus 300 yen shipping to Tenso, or 92.62 USD. It arrived within a day. Tenso to NY was 17300 yen shipping plus 2980 yen handling, minus my 4000 yen coupon, or 204.41 USD. If anyone can parse a "slow boat" shipping option that costs less, that would help. Otherwise, I have word of a new importer to the US that should have stock in May, also $25 per box but less adventure to order. I'll post again when that's official.

Comment: +1 for "Better to warn your credit card company in advance."

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for something better than Binney and Smith, and don't want to pay shipping from Japan, I really  like Quartet chalk.  They sell it in white:

[http://www.amazon.com/Quartet-Alpha-Nontoxic-Chalk-Sticks/dp/B002ZZ9FMC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002ZZ9FMC)

I have never bought the white, though, so I can't swear by it.

I do use their triple size ivory chalk.  I like it because it is thicker than regular chalk (so easier on the wrists and arms), and also because it is much denser than Binney and Smith.  You can find it at Office Depot:

http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/342246/Quartet-Alphasite-Triple-Size-Chalk-3/

I also swear by their colored chalk:

[http://www.amazon.com/Nontoxic-Colored-Assorted-Colors-QRT305003/dp/B0013CQ38W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=office-products&qid=1281560371&sr=8-1-catcorr](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013CQ38W)

They do have a stick of white in each packet of colored, and if that is the same as what they sell in what I listed first, then I can vouch for its quality.

One final note: this chalk claims to be low dust.  I disagree.  If you're looking for good dense chalk that shows up really well on the board, this is it.  But if you want to be clean at the end of the lecture, this is not for you.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what the name of this chalk manufacturer was.  I used it once before and really liked it. The coloured chalk is excellent.  The main problem I have with it is it breaks a little too easily.  The Hagoromo chalk above does not have that problem. But the Quartet chalk is in effect much cheaper.  

Comment: Paul Sally at UChicago exclusively used the triple-thickness Quarter chalk, and, as his TA, I became addicted to it.  Unfortunately, my university rolled the entire faculty over to whiteboards a few years before I came ….  (I know that UBC has done this, too, and assume that others will soon follow, bad trends being the ones that see the quickest adoption.)

Answer (score 1):

I was recently pointed to this site for buying Japanese chalk (white and color, Rikagaku brand), as well as other Japanese pens and office supplies. In particular, they sell the Japanese erasers that I believe Dylan referred to in his comment on the original question.

http://www.jetpens.com/

Comment: Actually, @Dylan was referring to the eraser *cleaners*, which are basically small specialized vacuum cleaners. I've never seen those sold outside Asia (jetpens included) -- if anybody has, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Comment: By the way, these are also used in South Korea -- this might be relevant for people in continental Europe, since South Korea has switched to 220V and type C/F plugs some time ago, so you could run a cleaner without an adapter.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read too quickly!  The Berkeley Math Dept has an eraser cleaner which presumably was bought outside Asia, but it looks like it is 50 years old, and I've never seen another.

Answer (score 1):

Umajirushi DC DX, which is supposed to be based off the Hagoromo formula is available on alibaba. At 24 boxes of 72 each, including shipping, it comes to about 13$ a box of 72. Is anyone interested in sharing an order?