# Good chalk in the UK

Tags: teaching, soft-question

Sometime ago it was asked in Mathoverflow about good chalk in the US [Where to buy premium white chalk in the U.S., like they have at RIMS?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26267/where-to-buy-premium-white-chalk-in-the-u-s-like-they-have-at-rims). I will be grateful for any recommendations on good chalk in the UK and where to get it.

Comment: I feel your pain, but I wonder whether despite the admittedly useful precedent this is an appropriate question. [I did not vote to close, by the way.]  (For what it's worth, I ended up buying my own chalk in Japan following a recommendation in the other question.)



Comment: Jose, yes the question might not fit a narrow interpretation of the rules. However, I see little difference between this question and the question I referred to. The question is very concise, so the “damage” is minimal and on the other hand the “benefit” to mathematics might be bigger than most normal questions. Finally, I see no alternative where I can find an answer to this question.

Comment: My brother bought me three boxes of Hagoromo Fulltouch Chalk by mail order from Japan. I am not aware of an off-the-shelf source in the UK, but who cares?

Comment: I did vote to close.  This isn't about research mathematics.  Lots of non-mathematical questions might benefit "the community" (for example, "How do you avoid embarrassing your kids at parent-teacher conferences?") but are still "off topic".  Just because a similar question was asked before is no guarantee (or justification) for it being asked again.  And there being no other place to ask such questions is similarly no reason to ask here.

Comment: I second the recommendation for Hagoromo mail-order.

Comment: So, how *do* you avoid embarrassing your kids at parent-teacher conferences?

Comment: Gerry, it's easy: "Neither the parent nor the teacher be".

Comment: I very nearly didn't ask that question for fear it was inappropriate. It is now, of course, my most highly rated and viewed question (by far).

Comment: Allen, "Walking in the rain" is _my_ most highly rated question by far.  3 of my top 4 by votes are closed, as are my top 5 by views.  The punch-line is that I agree with closing all of those (indeed, I initiated the closure of several) and think that none of them are good MO questions.  I tend to regard anything that gets more than 10 votes as being potentially suspect!

Comment: @AndrewStacey, in that case, I hope you voted to close the question linked-to as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently pointed to this site for buying Japanese chalk (white and color, Rikagaku brand), as well as other Japanese pens and office supplies.

http://www.jetpens.com/

They will ship internationally, though the shipping looks rather expensive.

Comment: http://www.jetpens.com/Chalks-Crayons/ct/1362 for a direct link to the chalk page.