# Chalkboard eraser

Tags: teaching

I just started my first year of university and because I'm visually impared I have trouble seeing what's written on the chalkboard.
I've partially solved this problem by purchasing chalk from hagoromo and asking my professors to use it. (Leaves a wider and nicer line and erases more cleanly).

But the chalkboard still gets dirty from chalk which reduces the contrast between the board and the chalk, which in turn makes it harder for me to see.

My university supplies what look to be whiteboard erasers for the blackboard which I suspect isn't a good idea.

I'm looking for suggestions for premium chalkboard eraser brands or DIY options.

Thanks

EDIT: My university washes all the boards regardless of department every day at the end of the day.
(At least in my campus).

Comment: In my experience the best method is to wash the board with a very wet sponge and then dry it with a window scraper. With some practice it is a quick procedure.

Comment: Which country are you in?  Germany and Scandinavian countries have better systems than elsewhere, with basins next to the boards and good implements to clean the board with water and then dry it.  One could probably order the implements by post, but they would be less useful without plumbing.

Comment: To echo @NeilStrickland strickland's comment: In Germany, this is at least true for lecture halls which are regularly used by mathematicians (and maybe physicists, though I'm not sure about the latter). Whenever I have to use a lecture hall that is typically used by another department, I'm at risk of getting a heart attack because they often lack the proper equipment to thoroughly clean the blackboard. Fortunately, one can buy certain water buckets which are specifically designed for cleaning the blackboard, and carry them to the lecture hall if necessary. Might that be a solution for the OP?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I am actually not sure if these long rectangular buckets are custom designed for blackboards or just for window cleaning. But in any case depending on the lecture hall, you might need to watch out for the floor. Copious amounts of water are great in cleaning blackboards, but I've seen blackboards mounted directly above carpet where this might be less of a good idea.

Comment: This isn't a research mathematics question. That isn't to say that it isn't an important question. You might try https://academia.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I don't think it should be the responsibility of a student to buy expensive chalk. If you are in the US or Canada, and I assume in many other countries as well, your university will have (it is a legal requirement) an office with a name like Student Accommodations or Accessibility Services or something like that. The purpose of those offices is to find ways to make classes accessible to everyone. It sounds like you have already found part of the solution. I recommend that you talk to that office, get them to require better chalk+erasers, and discuss further improvements for visibility.

Comment: @mlk: Those are good points indeed! Maybe those buckets are indeed specifically designed for cleaning windows rather than blackboards - but fortunately, they are still quite useful for blackboards, too. Concerning the carpets: Indeed, I've seen this often in offices. I guess I've (fortunately) never seen at in a lecture hall or seminar room, though. (But then again, I might well have overlooked it somewhere.)

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I agree with you that Academia SE is a better fit, but it also seems that mathematicians are disproportionately interested in chalk compared to any other academic department I can think of.

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren Thanks for your suggestion but as a student that's not really an option for me to do between classes.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I'm studying Physics and Computer Science at HUJI (Hebrew University of Jerusalem) and there they wash the boards once a day in all lecture halls regardless of department. I'm a student and 15 minutes between lectures is just enough time to get to the next lecture and stop at the WC if necessary. I'm looking for a solution to keep the boards clean. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Yes, sorry about that. The reason I posted it here is because of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26267/11260) thread about Hagoromo which helped me choose Hagoromo chalk. And Timothy Chow brought up another good reason to ask this question here.
As for me not being responsible for buying chalk, I agree, but someone has to do it, and they work really slowly, and here we are. Don't worry, my university has a special department called the learning center for the blind and they told me they would refund me for those purchases of chalk and erasers.

Comment: @TwoUnderscorez I did not expect you to do it. When I teach I wash the blackboard many times during each lecture and of course also at the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Hagoromo chalk, now produced in South Korea, is well accompanied by a professional Korean microfibre eraser (600,000 fibers per square inch), as explained by professor Bayer on his [Chalk page.](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~bayer/LinearAlgebra/Video/Chalk.php)

[image]
[image]

For more on chalk, there is this older [MO post.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26267/11260)

Comment: Thanks, I've ordered both the sponges and the cloth mentioned in the blog post.