# Is St. Petersburg a good place for the 2022 Int. Congress of Mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, conferences

There might be just enough time to pick another location, but I am curious what mathematicians think. Will Ukrainian mathematicians be able to attend a conference in Russia if Russia no longer recognizes their passports?

To be clear: I love Russia, and I am not trying to hurt the feelings of Russian mathematicians or people.

The International Mathematical Union (IMU) have made a [decision](https://www.mathunion.org/) on moving the ICM to a virtual event, but there is still the (less exciting) decision to make concerning the location of IMU General Assembly.

Comment: I posted something on meta about this: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5261/25028. To me this is a very borderline quesiton for the MO front page: it is inherently subjective and political; on the other hand, certainly it is of interest to research mathematicians. I'm conflicted as to whether it should be closed.

Comment: See also discussion on Peter Woit's blog: https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=12717.

Comment: LMS statement: https://www.lms.ac.uk/node/1848

Comment: I’m not sure this question can really be answered on MO, but my vote is “[expletive deleted] no.”

Comment: SMF (french) [statement](https://smf.emath.fr/actualites-smf/23-02-22-icm-en-russie). Last sentence: "The SMF urges the International Mathematical Union not to hold the ICM in Russia in 2022."

Comment: @abx There is a similar AMS statement.

Comment: Since much longer time, there is this call: http://www.icm2022boycott.org/

Comment: I see that there is a letter (finalised last Sunday) to the IMU leadership signed by 116 invited speakers to the ICM stating 'it [is] the responsibility of the IMU to ensure that the Congress will not take place within the context of a war, orof the threat of war.' See https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbcerqnd36w8xg2/ICMstatement.docx?dl=0.

Comment: "There might be just enough time to pick another location..." If I understand correctly, the IMU By-Laws require 6 months notice for the General Assembly (though not the ICM, which is a different bailiwick) to be moved. See By-Law 37 (and Statute 24) in the 2018 version. Though the language of the Statute 24 does seem to allow a "postal  ballot" to determine the time and place of the "normal" GA (as opposed to a "special" GA), with no immediately evident temporal restrictions therein.

Comment: There is now a statement from the IMU itself: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Publications/CircularLetters/2022/IMU%20AO%20CL%204_2022.pdf

Comment: Hey y'all - I'm one of the CMs here for Stack Exchange. I've removed some comments here. I understand today is beyond painful for many people and I don't want to dismiss that but I felt it was important to step in to keep this in scope of the question as asked. I understand that can be difficult considering recent events but it seemed like everyone agreed that the discussion had strayed a bit far, so I took the initiative to remove it.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for removing the discussion that I started. I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question in part as a small gesture of respect to the awesome calm bravery of the anti-war protestors in Moscow and other Russian cities--perhaps St. Petersburg as well. (I doubt I would be as brave.) And, I find the linked blog posts on the topic informative.

Comment: "Will Ukrainian mathematicians be able to attend a conference in Russia if Russia no longer recognizes their passports?" - this seems somewhat hypothetical. Even when countries are at war, there can be what might vaguely be called "cultural exceptions" to border controls. For instance, Levon Aronian of Armenia played in the 2015 Chess World Cup in Azerbaijan (though in 2016 the Armenian teams did not take part in the Chess Olympiad in Baku). My guess is that Ukrainian mathematicians *could* apply on a case-by-case basis to attend the ICM. My guess is also that approximately zero would do so.

Comment: IMHO, it should be a cw question.

Comment: Australian Mathematical Society says no: https://austms.org.au/statement-on-icm-2022/

Comment: I think this is an important question, and I do not know another place to discuss it. The comments so far al already very useful. Therefore, I am against closing.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question: there is a lot of useful information in the comments.

Comment: I vote to re-open: the question and the answer have high up vote.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I voted to reopen too. The question obviously doesn't fit the guidelines but it's too important.  Perhaps it can be moved to meta but I'm fine with it being here. Will get fewer views on meta.

Comment: There's an earlier comment indicating that the AMS has a statement regarding this, but it didn't include the link. Since people have posted links to the statements by the LMS, SMF, and Australian Math Soc, I thought it would be helpful to also give the link the the AMS statment, which was posted on February 22: https://www.ams.org/news?news_id=6987

Comment: The answer is an emphatic "No!". As for the clarification: May I suggest that the feelings of Ukrainian mathematicians should be given a higher priority than the feelings of Russian mathematicians at a time like this?

Comment: Letter to the editor of _Notices of the AMS_, to appear: "The International Mathematical Union should postpone the International Congress of Mathematics 2022 (ICM 2022) scheduled for St. Petersburg, Russia, in July, 2022, and announce that the meeting will take place in 2023 in another country.  The American Mathematical Society should immediately announce that it will not participate in any mathematics meeting in Russia in 2022.  If this were a theorem, one would add: Proof obvious. -Melvyn Nathanson."  Mel mentioned it was his first paper accepted in 1 hour 16 minutes.

Comment: @BrianHopkins, "If this were a theorem, one would add: Proof obvious." Great quote. It's unfortunate certain cadres in the U.S. don't think so clearly and too frequently have insidious agendas.

Comment: The World Chess Federation (which Arkady Dvorkovich is the head of it - relevantly, he's also the co-chair of the ICM executive organizing committee) recently announced that the 2022 Chess Olympiad will not take place in Russia (as had been planned). Dvorkovich ultimately made the decision himself (his Council was actually against moving/cancelling it a couple of days ago), saying "objectively it was necessary", but as there was significant IOC pressure, I'm unsure one can analogize that the ICM will be handled similarly.

Comment: Imagine a casual reader, not a mathematician: "wow, if this is a soft question, I wonder what the serious ones are on this site".

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte I'm not sure it's an important issue. I added the soft-question tag, which has a precise role which the casual reader can read just clicking the tag or just putting the mouse on it. Many more usual "soft question"-tagged questions are also not easy to answer, and also the "soft-question" tag is not suitable for mathematical questions even if easy to solve.

Comment: @YCor I'm sure the tag is more than appropriate (it was just bitter humor by me).

Comment: The Irish Mathematical Society has put out a strongly worded statement on this question: http://www.irishmathsoc.org/

Comment: The New Scientist has discussed the issue: https://www.newscientist.com/article/2309727-mathematicians-are-angry-that-russia-may-still-host-a-major-conference/

Comment: I voted to re-open this some time ago - could someone with enough points protect this question  from being closed? (I certainly will keep voting to reopen as many times as needed)

Comment: I voted to close because I feel that mathematics should be the reason for uniting people, not for dividing them. If there are security concerns I don't think MO is the place to discuss them

Comment: @godelian The dividing has already been done. Allowing the divider the prestige of hosting the ICM seems to me (and others) highly immoral, even without getting into security concerns.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I think their prestige has gone down the sink even if they hold the ICM. I just wish mathematics will not have to suffer for this.

Comment: The Swedish Mathematical Society has also sent such a statement (“åsiktsbrev”) to the IMU: [letter from 2022-02-25](https://swe-math-soc.se/pdf/SMStoIMU.pdf).  Also: [an earlier such appeal from 2021-11-26](https://swe-math-soc.se/pdf/opinion-letter-from-SMS-to-IMU.pdf).

Comment: @godelian Mathematics has already suffered for this, and will continue to suffer every day the lives of our colleagues in Ukraine are threatened and their country is destroyed.

Comment: From the Italian mathematical society website: https://umi.dm.unibo.it/2022/02/24/comunicato-umi-sulla-crisi-ucraina/

Comment: [This open letter](https://trv-science.ru/2022/02/we-are-against-war/) by Russian scientists is not directly related by ICM, but probably still worthwhile to mention in this context.

Comment: The quintessence of mathematics is the discovery, creation, and sharing of harmony, truth, and beauty. An offensive war is the atrocious antithesis. Although the trajectory of this terrible, heartbreaking debacle needs a thorough, honest review so that correctives can be made to the foreign policies of the nations involved, I commend the at least implicit condemnation of the Russian kleptocracy by boycotts of the ICM meeting.

Comment: I don't think the issue for Ukrainian mathematicians is so much whether they'd be let in, so much as the Russians can be trusted to let them leave.

Comment: @user334725 "Even when countries are at war, there can be what might vaguely be called "cultural exceptions" to border controls." If the Russians had any respect for international norms, we wouldn't be in this situation in the first place.

Comment: @JakubKonieczny "May I suggest that the feelings of Ukrainian mathematicians should be given a higher priority than the feelings of Russian mathematicians at a time like this?" Any Russian mathematician with any decency would object to it being held in Russian as well. So it's a question of whether the feelings of the Russian mathematicians who lack basic decency should take precendence.

Comment: A decision has been made: https://www.mathunion.org/

Comment: @BenMcKay: In light of this resolution, perhaps the question should be closed?

Comment: Ukrainian mathematicians are fighting the invader or hiding in bomb shelters as we speak while Russian mathematicians are [jailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azat_Miftakhov). Why would any place in Russia be a good location for any international event right now? Maybe - hopefully - in a few years when Putin's bloody regime is over, but "in 2022" would sound like an awful judgement call.

Comment: @SamHopkins: ok, I closed it.

Comment: @Mazura : edited as requested.

Comment: This question is off topic, but at the same time questions like this are the very reason I love this site and a reminder to keep the shred of faith in humanity.

Comment: Slightly more important than "Where to buy premium white chalk in the U.S., like they have at RIMS?", eh? (Check the voting and timeline for closure on that question.) As a moral issue, independent of logistics and security, the answer to BM's question is obvious to me, but I want to know the opinions and responses among the wider community. (I hope the total vote will exceed that for the one on chalk. As far as the # of views--well, hope springs eternal.)https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26267/where-to-buy-premium-white-chalk-in-the-u-s-like-they-have-at-rims

Comment: From https://ecmiindmath.org/2019/03/25/leonhard-euler-and-saint-petersburg/: These sixteen years spent in Saint Petersburg were very productive for Leonhard Euler. He came as a young graduate and left as a world-famous mathematician. In Saint Petersburg, he married Katharina Gsell, the daughter of another expat from Switzerland. But Russia had its specifics: when he was asked by the Prussian Empress: "Why are you speaking so briefly?”, he replied, “Your Majesty, I came from the country, where you can be executed for a word.”  (Some traditions die hard.)

Comment: The Scottish Café (famous among mathematicians interested in the history of the field) was a café in Lwów, Poland, which is now Lviv, Ukraine (https://dbpedia.org/page/Scottish_Caf%C3%A9). Lviv has my vote for an ICM when the time comes, with a tip of my hat to the generous Poles.

Answer (score 142):

To answer the question in the title: "No."

And I would imagine that Ukrainian mathematicians would boycott any ICM held in Russia, in these times. So the question of whether Russia would honor their passports will probably not arise.

Comment: I don't think the question arises whether the question arises because realistically the ICM will not be held in St. Petersburg.

Comment: Realistically (though perhaps I will be corrected), I don't think there were many Ukrainian mathematicians planning on attending even prior to recent events.

Comment: I don't even think this is about Ukranian mathematicians at this point.  Holding ICM in Russia is no longer tenable. If It's not moved many invited speakers will not go. At least I hope so. There are things more important than math honors.

Comment: I'd even go that far to say that such global event as an ICM should *ideally* take place in a location where nobody -- regardless from where in the world -- has the feeling to be in enemy's country, as far as this can realistically be achieved. But an ICM in St Petersburg this year would feel to me like an ICM in Munich in 1938.

Comment: @StefanKohl, you express something I think we all wish for. But do you have an actual location to suggest? I would add that I think to achieve such a goal, each ICM should be funded jointly by all IMU members (at appropriate percentages) instead of just the host country.

Comment: @DeaneYang While there is no *perfect* location, certainly a good approximation are small neutral countries (such as e.g. Switzerland or Austria) which were not involved in war in the past decades and which do not threaten other countries by military means. And yes, I also think funding should be by all IMU members -- already to avoid that only big or rich countries can host an ICM, or that commercial / PR considerations play a too big role.

Comment: Small neutral countries that will allow visa-free travel or expedited visas without a humiliating and expensive process for citizens of every country (and yes, third-world countries are countries). Something tells me that not every small neutral country in Europe fits the bill.

Answer (score 62):

The real question is not about the Congress. There will be no ICM in Petersburg. Maximum what they can stage is a Russian-Chinese conference. Which decent Russians and Chinese will not attend anyway.

The real question is about moral character of the IMU leadership. It is they who made a decision to have this congress in the country which is controlled by a maniac mass murderer sitting on 5000+ nukes. Everyone knew what kind of country is this since 2014.

And even in these last two days, when bombs and missiles are falling on all major Ukrainian cities, the IMU committee is still "discussing" something!

Edit. Meanwhile, sports federations cancel all events in Russia and even tourist tour operators cancel their tours. Only IMU is still "deliberating".

Update: It seems that they [finally decided](https://www.mathunion.org/).

Comment: In fairness, they may be discussing whether it is feasible to move ICM to another location in either 2022 or 2023, versus canceling it altogether. The logistical and financial issues in organizing a huge conference such as the ICM in 5 months, or even 17 months, are daunting. I have no inside knowledge, but I do feel it's okay to give them the weekend to decide what to do. Of course, they should issue an initial statement saying "no ICM in Russia", or the stronger statement "no ICM with any host participation by Russia," with additional details to follow. I guess we both would have liked that.

Comment: @JoeSilverman "no ICM with any host participation by Russia," I'm not sure what exactly that statement means, but still want to attract everybody's attention that there is a difference between V. Putin and Stas Smirnov, so I wouldn't mind moving ICM to another country with retaining most of the organizing committee, if they are willing to serve. As to the initial IMU decision, it was, probably, based not on the number of nukes or the character of the country's leader, but on the reputation of the Russian mathematical school, so I see no moral issue there. But let them speak for themselves.

Comment: @fedja: Still nobody proposed the 1940 ICM in Germany. It was just canceled. And those who proposed it in post 2014 Russia bear full moral responsibility.

Comment: @fedja: Of course, there is a lot of difference between Putin and Smirnov. I suppose Putin is not a good mathematician. And Putin is a mass murderer, while Smirnov is only a collaborationist. Smirnov lives and works in a free European country. Did he ever publicly dissociate himself from Putin's crimes?

Comment: @JoeSilverman Excluding mathematicians from one country just because that country's leader is insane would be totally unacceptable.

Comment: @MartinHairer I was not suggesting that invited Russian ICM speakers be excluded from speaking about their mathematical work. They should be welcomed. I was suggesting that Russia should not serve as the host country. Hosting might include (for example) having host dignitaries welcoming the participants. I have the greatest respect for our Russian colleagues and the achievements of Russian mathematicans. But the (to quote your words) insane leadership of the country should preclude that country from having the honor of hosting the ICM. My impression is that IMU has reached the same decision.

Comment: I certainly hope your relatives, friends, and colleagues in the Ukraine and in Russia will see this tragedy through unharmed.

Comment: @Tom Copeland: Currently some of them leave their homes and escape, others sitting in bomb shelters, while the younger ones took arms to defend themselves.

Answer (score 50):

The IMU [reached their decision](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/ICM2022/ICM_2022_statement.pdf), the ICM will take place entirely virtually except for the IMU general assembly and awards ceremony which will take place in-person outside of Russia. <strike>No word on whether Russian government involvement in organizing will continue.</strike>  Further details to come.

Terry Tao, who is the chair of the ICM Structure Committee, is inviting discussion of how to best use the virtual format [on his blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2022/02/26/the-international-congress-of-mathematicians-icm-2022-will-now-be-fully-virtual-how-best-to-utilise-this-format/).

The IMU executive committee has released [some further clarifications](https://twitter.com/monsoon0/status/1498036491045728257), including announcing that there will be no Russian government involvement in the ICM.

Comment: Feel free to edit, this was an attempt at a neutral summary of the announcement.

Comment: I added a link to Terry Tao's blog, a better place for wide-ranging discussions than MO (though note that he specifically requests the discussion be restricted to the *format* of the ICM, and not the underlying politics).

Comment: @SamHopkins The link does not work for me

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Huh, works fine for me. The front page of his blog is also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/ which you can type in directly.

Comment: @SamHopkins There is some problem on my side then - I cannot access the front page either

Comment: @SamHopkins Something weird is going on. I can access it via Tor browser but neither  via Firefox nor Chrome. I can access wordpress.com via all browsers, but searching for terrytao there produces no results in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: They should consider holding the in-person meeting in Helsinki since (1) it is easily accessible to the St. Petersburg organizers by train and (2) it is the location of the signing of the Helsinki accords.

Comment: [Good call](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Publications/CircularLetters/2022/IMU%20AO%20CL%209_2022.pdf) @KConrad

Comment: That's nice. Anyone who goes there for the ICM should be sure to visit Keskuskatu, a central street in Helsinki that was paved with a Penrose tiling in 2014.

Comment: @NoahSnyder my train comment is no longer applicable: https://www.euronews.com/2022/03/25/finland-to-stop-eu-s-last-direct-train-link-with-russia.